# Can git store the mime-type of a file, like SVN does, for browsing html?

Tags: svn, git, github

I've just pushed my first repo to github but when I browse my html it is served as txt. Is this something that I can set similar to svn's props? Or is this simply a github inadequacy?

I can't seem to find anything on git, github or here that helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Git, unlike SVN is not concerned with individual files, rather with commits so I believe you cannot set mime-type props on files. On the other hand, github is a "code hosting site", which manages your code repositories and is only concerned about showing code. The exception from this rule is README files, where you can sort-of specify different formats (like .markdown) and render them as semi-HTML and wiki pages.

If what you want is to host your HTML files (like in a webserver) then github is not the place to do it. Rather, you can keep your files under github's version control, but check out and serve them from a webserver like apache.

Comment: There's also [github pages](http://pages.github.com/) which lets you host arbitrary HTML.

Comment: Correct, git doesn't store it although TECHNICALLY it could in the tree.

Comment: If your repository happens to contain a few (or many) HTML files (eg documentation), it would be nice if GitHub served them as HTML if you press "raw".  You're in a web browser after all!

Comment: In addition to [github pages](http://pages.github.com/), there is [HTML Preview](http://htmlpreview.github.com/) feature. It allows to pass any GitHub URL as GET parameter like this:  

http://htmlpreview.github.com/?https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/docs/index.html

Answer (score 9):

First, Subversion supports (versioned) properties (simple *key=value* pairs) on files, directories and revisions.  This includes `svn:mime-type` property for a file.  This approach (this feature) looks like remnants of original BerkeleyDB storage engine, and reminds a bit "resource forks" on (older?) MacOS filesystems.

The closest equivalent of Subversion's file properties in Git would be **[gitattributes](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes)** (per-path attributes).  You could define `mime-type` gitattribute, but currently no Git tool (known to me) uses it.  Note that in contrast to Subversion gitattributes are stored in an ordinary file: in-tree `.gitattributes` file (which can be versioned), and per repository user's `.git/info/attributes` file... which can be edited in ordinary editor, and not only using SCM commands.

Second, mime-types or mimetype-like property or attribute is not really necessary.  Gitweb (and probably other git interfaces) use file with extension to mimetype mapping (`/etc/mime.types` by default), so that e.g. '*.html' files are served *in 'raw' mode (i.e. 'blob_plain' action)* are served with 'text/html' content-type, see e.g. http://repo.or.cz/w/git.git/blob_plain/html:/gitattributes.html

It's the lack in GitHub web interface that http://github.com/git/git/raw/html/gitattributes.html is served with 'text/plain' content-type...

Comment: about `mime-type` git attribute, i cannot find it on git docs

Comment: @danza: I wrote "you could *define* `mime-type` attribute", i.e. it would be **custom** attribute (like e.g. `encoding` attribute used by git-gui, but not defined by git itself).

Answer (score 2):

File extension to mime-type mapping is, at best, a broken workaround. Two examples among many. Prolog used the .pl extension long before Perl existed. Files with a .txt extension may contain e.g. Markdown text and there often are good reasons to not use a .md or similar extension.

Comment: Leaving comments as answers is, at best, ... . ;)